# What does `namespaceMappings` mean in Word.CustomXMLPart API

Tags: ms-word, office-js, word-addins

I have created a small snippet in [Script Lab](https://gist.github.com/algomaster99/52f08d3360119d47a850e1a08cba90a8) which basically:

1. Creates a custom XML:

```xml
<AP xmlns="accordproject.org">
  <template xmlns="acceptance-of-delivery">
    <shipper>Aman Sharma</shipper>
  </template> 
</AP>
```

2. Tries to query this xml by using the xPath `/AP/template`. I run this block of code:

```js
await Word.run(async context => {
  const customXmlParts = context.document.customXmlParts;
  const AP = customXmlParts.getByNamespace("accordproject.org").getOnlyItemOrNullObject();
  await context.sync();
  const nodes = AP.query('/AP/template', {}); // how does this work?
  await context.sync();
  console.log(nodes);
})
```

3. Deletes the customXML.

The second argument of [`query`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.customxmlpart?view=word-js-preview#query-xpath--namespacemappings-) API is `namespaceMappings`. I think I am passing that incorrectly and that's why I get this as ouput (empty object).
[image: empty array]

But when I pass `*` instead of `/AP/template`, I get the whole XML (while the second argument, `namespaceMappings` remain the same).

Where am I going wrong? Can anyone share some snippets to help me query customXML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you can use

```
const nodes = AP.query("/n1:AP/n2:template", {n1:"accordproject.org", n2:"acceptance-of-delivery"});
```

I don't know JS/TS at all but I assume these are basically key-value pairs of some kind. You can also use

```
const nodes = AP.query("/n1:AP/n2:template", {"n1":"accordproject.org", "n2":"acceptance-of-delivery"});
```

if you prefer to think of the Namespace prefixes as strings.

(For anyoneunfamiliar, the "n1" and "n2" are just prefixes that you invent so you can reference the full Namespace URIs. They don't have anything to do with any prefixes you might have used in the piece of XML you are querying.)

I couldn't find documentation on this either and originally assumed you might need something more like {  Prefix:"ns1", namespaceURI:"the namespace URI" }, but that's just because those are the property names used in the VBA model.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I tried this approach but it now gives me `InvalidArgument` error and it seems `CustomXmlPart.query` throws the error. I think the arguments are something else.

Comment: Oh no. I just had multiple XML files. I guess that was the problem :)
`AP.query("/n1:AP/n2:template", {n1:"accordproject.org", n2:"acceptance-of-delivery"});` By the way, can you double-check if this works too? I am not near my laptop.

Comment: Thanks to you both. I will update the documentation. Question: Does the following work? `AP.query("/accordproject.org:AP/acceptance-of-delivery:template", {});`

Comment: @RickKirkham: I checked that, and it does *not* work. AFAICR it should not really work because you are supposed to use prefixes, but I'm sure neither of us really wants to wade through the XPath spec. to make sure!

Comment: Thanks @slightlysnarky. You've helped a lot. I will get the documentation updated.